# event.preventDefault stops social media icons from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').scrollspy({target: "#navbar", offset: 50});   
$("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var hash = this.hash;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 2150, function(){
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
     
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#section1"><h5><b>Home</b></h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#section3"><h5><b>other</b></h5></a></li> 
<li><a href="#section5"><h5><b>other2</b></h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#section6"><h5><b>other3</b></h5></a></li>
     </ul>
        <div id="social_nav">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="https://uk.pinterest.com" target="blank"><span class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-2x"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="blank"><span class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"  target="blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hi,
I have a bootstrap nav with scrollspy moving smoothly between sections on the page.
This uses `event.preventDefault();` to stop the page jumping about and is fine. However i have a second part of the nav with social media icons that need to link to a webpage, and these are also stopped from working by `event.preventDefault();`

Is there a was of stopping `event.preventDefault();` for the social media icons but leaving it for the other page nav items please.

Bit of web diy noob so maybe this is easy, but I'm foxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just exclude the social icons from the event handler

```
$("#myNavbar a").not('#social_nav a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    ....
});
```

Should do it, there's no reason to scroll to those icons when clicked, as they redirect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The preventDefault is stopping the links from executing their default behavior, in this case going to the linked URL.  It's a bit of a hacky solution, but you could add a class (social-link in the example) to any links in the navbar that need to go to a real URL, then restore that behavior in your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').scrollspy({target: "#navbar", offset: 50});

  $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;

    if (this.hasClass('social-link')) {
      window.location = this.href;
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top }, 2150, function(){ });
    }
  });
});
```